# OnAppearing check from which Page the User is comming in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way i can detect, from which page the user is coming inside of the OnAppearing event in a ContentPage? As well as by pushing a Page to the Navigation or poping it.

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if(/*User comes from certain page*/){
        //Do stuff
    }else{
        //Do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Navigation Stack?

Comment: @DakshalRaijada Yes, sorry should have mentioned that. I'm Using Navigation stack and Call Navigation.PushAsync(new Page()) or  Navigation.PopAsync(); to navigate back an forth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `NavigationStack` you can view the `Page`s that have been pushed into the stack.

```
content.Appearing +=  (sender, e) =>
{
    var pages = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;
    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(page.Title);
    }
};
```

Thus, you just have to look at the second to last page to determine where you are coming from....

Something like:

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Reverse().Take(2).Last();
```

Comment: Okay i see it now. for me it is confusing, that in case of a 'Navigation.PopAsync();' the poped page is still in the NavigationStack.